# Collection View Not Visible in Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I am extremely new at Xcode. I am building an app that has a collection view in it. It looks great in the storyboard view, but nothing shows up when I run the simulator. I have images and labels in the cells. I have created a subclass for the cells and made my connections for the images and labels into the .h file. For right now I am just making a stub prototype (cells don't link to anything). If anyone can give me an answer or just suggest something to try than that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a **dynamic prototype** - to actually show data, you need to read up on **`datasources`** and **`delegates`**.

If I were you, I would start with trying to make a simple `UITableView` app first. Google `UITableView tutorial` to get started.

After you're familiar with the above concepts, then would I suggest to go through a collection view tutorial - it's a relatively simple set of concepts when you get it, but you have to get it first :)

Comment: When I have the collection view connected to the View Controller as datasource and delegate I get the Thread 1 signal sigabrt. Any suggestions there?